# Why are the results of of str == str.intern() for StringBuilder using append or not different?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, string-interning

All.I have a java code snippet like this:

```
 String a = new StringBuilder("app").append("le").toString();
 System.out.println(a.intern() == a);
 String b = new StringBuilder("orange").toString();
 System.out.println(b.intern() == b);
```

and this java code will output true,false.
I wonder why. Thanks All.

Answer (score 11):

In both cases, `StringBuilder.toString()` creates a new string.

In the first case, `String.intern()` finds that there's no string "apple" in the intern pool, so adds the provided one to the pool and returns the same reference - which is why it prints `true`.

In the second case, `String.intern()` finds that there's already a string "orange" in the intern pool, so returns a reference to that - which is a different reference to `b`, hence it prints `false`.

Note that if you had a line before the start of this code of:

```
System.out.println("apple");
```

then you'd see `false` from the first comparison too, for the same reason.